# In SQL*Plus, how do I change the prompt to show the connected user and database?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

To show, for example....

```
USER@SID >
```

I thought this was potentially helpful to a few people so I'm going to answer it too!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Amend your $ORACLE_HOME\sqlplus\admin\glogin.sql script - add:

```
set sqlprompt "_user '@' _connect_identifier > "
```

to the end of the file.

In Oracle 10g this will change correctly each time you issue a "conn".  For clients before 10g it won't change when you do a "conn" but will remain as the username/db you first connected to.

You can also use _date for the current date and _privilege for the privilege (eg SYSDBA) of the connected user.

Reference:

http://www.acs.ilstu.edu/docs/Oracle/server.101/b12170/whatsnew.htm

Comment: This is also answered in this [SQL*Plus FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Plus_FAQ#Can_one_set_the_SQL.2APlus_command_prompt_to_something_more_useful.3F).