# sqplplus - echo current login info

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

Is there a way to echo/print the current connection string in sqlplus? I have a script that will be run in multiple databases, and I'd like a line at the top that looks like:

`Currently executing test_script.SQL as USER1@MY_DB`

It would be very convenient if there was a way to do this without having to change the file itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the built-in SQL*Plus substitution variables _USER and _CONNECT_IDENTIFIER.

Add the following line to your SQL*Plus script:

```
prompt Currently executing test_script.SQL as &_USER@&_CONNECT_IDENTIFIER
```

Here is the [link to the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve017.htm#SQPUG038).

Comment: Thanks! I guess there's nothing for the name of the file, but that only needs to change when new scripts are created, so it's not so bad.

Answer (score 2):

See this question:

[In SQL*Plus, how do I change the prompt to show the connected user and database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303940/in-sqlplus-how-do-i-change-the-prompt-to-show-the-connected-user-and-database)