# Change Oracle prompt to variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following PLSQL code and I would like to change the prompt to variable but I am not sure about the syntax. Unfortunately Google search did not help.

**PLSQL code snippet:**

```
set define off
set define on
set define $
set serveroutput on

spool abc.log

accept schema_owner prompt "schema owner: "
accept tbsp prompt "tablespace: "
alter session set current_schema=$schema_owner;
...
```

**I would like to have something like this:**

```
...
schema_owner := "apple"
tbsp := "apple_tbl"
...
```

Could you please help me in?

Comment: That's not PL/SQL - it's SQL*Plus, client side scripting. Are you saying you want to change the SQLPlus prompt as well? That's addressed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303940/in-sqlplus-how-do-i-change-the-prompt-to-show-the-connected-user-and-database

Comment: Yes, I would like to remove the prompts from my SQL code and I would like to substitute them with hardcoded values. To use SQL script params like "@my.sql aaa bbb ccc" is not option.

Comment: "them with hardcoded values." Then why us variables at all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking to use substitution variables.

```
set define off
set define on
set define $
set serveroutput on
spool abc.log
DEFINE schema_owner = 'HR'
DEFINE tbsp = 'DATA'

alter session set current_schema = $schema_owner;


SQL>         alter session set current_schema = $schema_owner;
old   1:     alter session set current_schema = $schema_owner
new   1:     alter session set current_schema = HR

Session altered.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can see that I need to remove the '$' character as well. Is there any solution where I can keep it?

Comment: @zappee : check now.